# any way to use tail to get the value before the last (or other values without knowing the total number of lines)

Tags: bash

I use tail to grab a finite amount of lines from a file, but now I am trying to grab not the last one, but the one before (or any arbitrary number, starting from the bottom).

`Tail -n 1` will return me the last entry, but how can I extract a different number, knowing only the distance from the last one?

In most cases I need the last 2, so I do a `tail -n 2` and I grab them, but would be awesome if I could just get back one entry, specifying how many positions from the bottom.

I was looking into sed and awk; but they seems utterly complex, while I was hoping in a simple one line command, which is the simplest solution.

In the worst case I can just grab the last 2 lines, and then check where the line ends and divide them in 2 variables, but I am sure that there is a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply pipe the output of `tail` through `head`. For example, to get the second-to-last line, you can do

```
tail -n 2 filename | head -n 1
```

By combining `head` and `tail` like this you can get any range of lines you want relative to either the beginning or the end of the file.

Comment: Just brilliant! forgot about head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
tail -n 2 filename | sed '2d'
```

In the above command the sed will take the output of tail command and simply delete the 2nd line....

Comment: Note that this returns the nth-last line only with input `2` (penultimate line), because the `sed` command only removes the 2nd line from `tail`'s output.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @hammar's excellent answer:

Here's a **bash function that returns the nth-LAST line(s)** (last line by default) from the input provided via `stdin`:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   getNthLast [n [count]]
getNthLast() {
  tail -n ${1:-1} | head -n ${2:-1}
}
```

Examples:

```
# Get the 5th-last line from file `file`:
getNthLast 5 < file

# Starting with the 3rd-to-last line from file `file`, return 2 lines:
getNthLast 3 2 < file
```

---

Here's a **bash function that returns the nth-FIRST line(s)** (1st line by default) from the input provided via `stdin`:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   getNth [n [count]]
getNth() {
  local n=${1:-1} count=${2:-1} e
  e=$(( n + count - 1 ))
  sed -n "$n,$e p; $e q"
}
```

Examples:

```
# Get the 5th line from file `file`:
getNth 5 < file

# Starting with the 3rd line from file `file`, return 2 lines:
getNth 3 2 < file
```

Comment: Awesomely done! That's the kind of simplicity that I like. Can't decide between your answer and Hammar.....you both deserve a green check!

Comment: @newbiez: Thanks; I suggest you give it to hammar, because he came up with the approach and succinctly answered your question; my answer is "syntactic sugar" on top.